# Подключение файла cs из вложенной папки в проект

Tags: c#

Как подключить файл cs из вложенной папки в проекте.
При подключении имеющегося элемента в проект файл появляется в корне проекта, а нужно подключить без дублирования файла

Comment: `using folder_name` :-)

Comment: "Add Existing Item" - "Add As Link"

Comment: Где находится этот Add Existing Item

Comment: Контекстное меню проекта.

Comment: Можно руками отредактировать csproj-файл и добавить все нужное. Если хотите все сделать мышкой - переместите куда-нибудь папку, которая в проекте не отображается; создайте папку через контекстное меню проекта; скопируйте содержимое из старой папки в новую; подключите файлы через контекстное меню проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Если не хотите использовать "Add Existing Item", то создайте аналогичную иерархию папок в вашем проекте, после чего создайте файл *.cs в нужной папке и скопируйте в него код. После чего, чтобы использовать данный файл в другом файле, необходимо дописать в хедере файла директиву using *. Хотя Intelli Sense позволяет это сделать без использования клавиатуры, если вы уже начали пользоваться ресурсами подключаемого файла.